# Property value update from Jenkins A’s project to Jenkins B’s project

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have two build jobs.

1. Jenkins_A
2. Jenkins_B

How can Jenkins_A change the property value from Jenkins_B job's property file?

Comment: Provide some more information. You may want to pass the parameter from Job A ->Job B and update the properties based on that ?

Comment: No. Let's say I have set properties in Jenkins job A. For example, ID=34,name=xyz. Now I want to use this property in another Jenkins job B and wants to update its value from Jenkins Job B. Like ID=78 and name=mnq.